# Multiple rows generation in a table with ngFor in Angular

Tags: angular

I have an object for with i need to create a row to show its data and another row to fill some value. If i am using ngFor, then i am able to populate data in one row or showing columns to be filled. I am not able to do it together. If i use ng-template, then for the first row alone i am getting combination of both. Please advise.

```
<tbody>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let request of assignedRequestFilteredValue | orderBy: 'modifiedDate' :true  | paginate: {itemsPerPage: itemsPerPage, currentPage: currentPage}; let i = index">
        <tr  class="visible-row" >
          <td><button class="btn btn-plain btn-sm accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo2"><span
                class="icon-gdpns_right"></span></button></td>
          <td>{{request.elecCommodity.name}}</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control form-control border-form-control"></td>
          <td>{{request.elecWflNewAmlitem[0].elecWflNewCommentHistoryAmlitem[0].comment}}</td>
          <td>{{request.elecWflNewAmlitem[0].customerMfrname}}</td>
          <td>{{request.elecWflNewAmlitem[0].customerMpn}}</td>
          <td>{{request.elecWflMasterCEStatus.description}}</td>
          <td>{{request.partNumberStatus.description}}</td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-md btn-outline-blue" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">View
              Details</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hidden-row">
          <td colspan="9" class="p-0">
            <div class="accordian-body collapse" id="demo2" style="padding:0.75rem">
              <app-ce-new-part-validation></app-ce-new-part-validation>
            </div>

          </td>
        </tr>

      </ng-container>

    </tbody>
```

Expected result should be as follows:

Row1 data
Row1 Fill data

Row2 data
Row2 Fill data

Row3 data
Row3 Fill data

Comment: What is current output now?

Comment: it is like row1 data \n row 1/2/3 fill data \n row2 data \n row3 data

Comment: What does the object look like?

Comment: it's normal. ```<tr>``` is a table row, so the above code should show two lines per object in your collection. So your output should really be:
```Row 1 data [newline] Row 1 hidden-row (app-ce-new-part-validation) [newline] Row 2 data [newline] Row 2 hidden-row (app-ce-new-part-validation) [newline] ...```
You should add a ```<td colspan="x">``` inside your first ```<tr>``` if you want those two parts to be displayed on the same line.

Comment: for each object first row should have data and second row should have data to be filled. this is coming correctly for first object. if i am referring second row, it is referring first object's second row